# Enriching Excel data/rows by referencing %shares in another table

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel, what VBA code will help me explode/enrich data in table A by applying the % shares in table B to produce the desired output in table C? Not all companies need to be enriched.

#### screenshot of relevant tables in Excel

[image: screenshot of relevant tables in Excel]

I envisage some loop to match on company name and then to enrich Table B by inserting the necessary rows to show the resulting shared $ by Team.

Comment: Welcome to [so], anything you have tried before? And you may try to use some build-in function in Excel first.  Moreover, [so] not a place to request code.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use Power Query for that, not VBA. Load both table A and Table B into Power Query. Then create a query that merges the two tables on the company column, using a full outer join. Then extract the team and share columns. Create a new column for the calculation of the $ value, delete the columns not required and remove null values from the Team column. The result looks like this:

[image]

M Code generated by clicking the buttons in Power Query Editor and entering one IF statement manually looks like this:

```
let
    Source = Table.NestedJoin(TableA,{"company"},TableB,{"company"},"NewColumn",JoinKind.FullOuter),
    #"Expanded NewColumn" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Source, "NewColumn", {"Team", "PercShare"}, {"Team", "PercShare"}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded NewColumn", "Dollars", each if [Team] = null then [dollar] else [dollar] *([PercShare]/100)),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"PercShare"}),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Removed Columns",null,"",Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Team"})
in
    #"Replaced Value"
```

Comment: Hi @teylyn. thanks for looking into this. I hadn't realized you'd answered as I can't recall getting an email notification. Unfortunately I don't have Power Query Editor and so can't implement your solution. I'll keep looking. Chrs

Comment: Stackoverflow does not send emails. You have to come here and look. Power Query is a free download from Microsoft for Excel 2010 and 2013 and built into 2016